# Where is the fifth photo in Following Role Models?

Tags: trauma

I managed to unlock every ending of Following Role Models which grants me a very vague description of the location of every photo.

Using this, I managed to find all but the fifth photo. Wherever I go, it never seems to switch away from "Very Far Away".

Where am I supposed to be looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the fifth photo by going to the weight:

[image]

1. Turn around the weight, by clicking on it.
2. Click the top right corner, to get to front side of the crane.
3. Click the top right corner again, to look upwards.
4. Now you should find the 5th photo on the crane window.

[image]